# Linker error on MS Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I get this error:

```
1>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0 
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. 
1>Linking... 
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'imqb23vn.Lib;imqc23vn.Lib'
```

how to resolve this error?

Comment: Are these libs something you need for yout project or are they VS's own?

Comment: yes these are the libs which i need in my project

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the linker is looking for a file named: `imqb23vn.Lib;imqc23vn.Lib`, instead of two files, named `imqb23vn.Lib` and `imqc23vn.Lib`.  Can you update your question with the value of _Project Property_ -> _Configuration Properties_ -> _Linker_ -> _Input_ -> _Additional Dependencies_?

Comment: In Project Property -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies its imqb23vn.Lib;imqc23vn.Lib
the same configuration settings works fine in visual studio 2010

Comment: Try replacing the semicolon (`;`) with a space between the two lib names

Answer (score 0):

*Note*: Moving answer from comments to proper post

The problem is that the linker is looking for a file named: `imqb23vn.Lib;imqc23vn.Lib`, instead of two files, named `imqb23vn.Lib` and `imqc23vn.Lib`

Apparently, the way libraries need to be listed in VS2008 is different from the way it is in VS2010.  You need to separare the .lib files in VS2008 by space, whereas separating them by semicolon (`;`) works in VS2010.